# Permissions error when exporting slideshow as a movie in iPhoto

Tags: macos, upgrade, photos.app, slideshow, video

I recently upgraded to Lion.

Now when I try to export an iPhoto slideshow as a QuickTime movie it goes through the initial rendering process but an error message appears with the iPhoto logo saying that I don't have permission for this task.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some people report issues with permissions and the desktop and/or other user folders. Try repair permissions with Disk Utility

Comment: Many thanks for that - I think I'm an Apple Dumbo  (just fairly recently moved from Windows).  Have just tried setting the save to a folder other than the "Shared Folder" it defaulted to, and hey presto, it worked.  Probably nothing to do with LION or iPhoto.